# How to test single newly created pod during rollout deployment in Kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes, testing

I have been working on the ci/cd pipeline for deploying our app to Kubernetes, while rolling out the deployment I want to run tests on a single newly-created pod, and if the test passes only then roll out the remaining pods.

is this even possible?

Comment: what kind of test are you trying to run?

Comment: simple mocha tests

Comment: Refer to this document on [Deplyoment](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/) which may help you to resolve your issue.